# Can't sign data with Nami Wallet

Tags: nami-wallet, message-signing

I'm facing a problem when I try to sign data with Nami Wallet API.

Here is the code snippet:

```
let namiAPI = await window.cardano.nami.enable();
let addr = await namiAPI.getUsedAddresses();
let payload = "48656C6C6F20576F726C6421"; //hex of "Hello World!"
let signed = await namiAPI.signData(addr.get(0), payload);
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "code": 4,
    "info": "If a wallet enforces data format requirements, this error signifies that the data did not conform to valid formats."
}
```

What could be the problem? Am I encoding the payload wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That payload looks good, just the address seems invalid. Probably need to access the array via `addr[0]` instead of `addr.get(0)`, try this:

```
let namiAPI = await window.cardano.nami.enable();
let addr = await namiAPI.getUsedAddresses();
let payload = "48656C6C6F20576F726C6421"; //hex of "Hello World!"
let signed = await namiAPI.signData(addr[0], payload);
```